# Want to use switcher function in class component of react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

I am not able to use this switcher method in my react app. which is build using class components
Suggest me way to use this switcher method of useThemeSwitcher() function in class components.

How can i Use or (write )this function in my web app.???

In this method switcher function is used in functional component..

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useThemeSwitcher } from "react-css-theme-switcher";
import { Switch } from "antd";

function App() {
 const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = React.useState("false");
  const { switcher, themes } = useThemeSwitcher();


const toggleTheme = (isChecked) => {
setIsDarkMode(isChecked);
switcher({ theme: isChecked ? themes.dark : themes.light })
 };

return (
<div className="main fade-in">
 
  <Switch checked={isDarkMode} onChange={toggleTheme} />

</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I want use switcher function in this code..

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Button, Menu, Popconfirm, Dropdown, Select } from 'antd';
import { useThemeSwitcher } from "react-css-theme-switcher";
import { Switch, Input } from "antd";

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isDarkMode:false,            
        };
    }
    


 toggleTheme = (isChecked)=>
 {
   this.setState({isDarkMode:isChecked ? true : false})
 }
    
    render() {
      
        return (
            <div className="main fade-in">
               <Switch checked={this.state.isDarkMode} onChange={this.toggleTheme} />
              </div>
          )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: `useThemeSwitcher ` is a hook. You can't use in class based component. Check library class based approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a hook you'll need to use it in a functional component. Simply translate your class component to a functional one.

```
const Header = () => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);
  // Now we can use it
  const { switcher, themes } = useThemeSwitcher();

  return <div className="main fade-in">
    <Switch checked={this.state.isDarkMode} onChange={setIsDarkMode} />
  </div>;
};
```